# Laravel x AngularJS $http.post authentication issue

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, request

I've successfully sent some information through AngularJS to my backend in Laravel, however, I'm facing some issues while trying to get some authenticated user data.

Basically, it just don't retrieve any authenticated user data from my backend.

**AngularJS**

```
 $scope.generatePrescription = function () {


        //check for token in meta tag
        var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

        console.log('CSRF_TOKEN =>'+csrf_token);




        info = {
            _token: csrf_token,
            receita: $scope.receita,
            receita_info: $scope.receita_info
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiURL + '/prescription/create',
            data: info,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        }).then(
            function(response){
                console.log(response.data)
            },
            function(error){
                console.log(error.data)
            }
        );

    }
```

**Api.php (Laravel)**

```
Route::middleware('api')->post('/prescription/create','Dashboard\PrescriptionController@store');
```

**PrescriptionController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request, Prescription $prescription)
{

    //receive prescription object
    $data = $request->json()->all();


    if(auth()->check()){
        return 'authenticated!!!';
    } else {
        return 'user is not authenticated..';
    }

}
```

How should I proceed to get my authenticated user variables?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your `api` middleware doesn't include `sessions` then you won't be able to   access the user model directly. An API is typically for token based authentication, and is stateless.

Comment: Ok. My problem is: I cannot pass the user_id to my backend trough a $http.post request since it's will certainly be a significant security flaw. So, I'm trying to retrieve the authenticated user data from my backend, which seems impossible to do.
Do you have any suggestion? How can I include this session into the API middleware?

Comment: Well, it defeats the purpose of `api` middleware to include a session. You can just change the middleware to `auth` and it'll work pretty much..